# Hide nameservers in public whois?

Tags: hide, public, whois, nameservers

Is there a way to hide the nameservers of my hosting provider in the public whois?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't hide such information. A few registries don't disclose them, but it's very limited number.

Some DNS providers offer a feature called "vanity name servers" that allow you to use custom name servers, if your purpose is to hide the name of the hosting provider to curious eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes no sense over at least 2 points, and you should accept not to try pursuing something as pure vanity.

Here is why:

- first whois is not the authoritative source on which nameservers are used for a given domain name, the DNS is;
- and the DNS is public because otherwise if your nameservers are "hidden" then your domain name (like your website, emails, etc.) would not work at all.

And even if all the above would not be the case, your website ultimately resolve to an IP address and with just that information people could find out who is the hosting company. Which is why "vanity nameservers" do not help at all.

So there is no shame in having anyone know who hosts your website.
Or, if you are so ashamed of your hosting provider for whatever personal reasons, then it is time to switch, there are a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach out to your web host and request a private registration.
here is a link from godaddy.
https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/420/adding-private-registration-to-your-domain-names

Comment: I have already registered private nameservers at Namecheap but my hosting provider was still visible in the public whois, probably due to the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to mask your nameserver is using services like cloudflare. However, if you purchased your domain from Namecheap it will surely appear as the domain registrant. but cloudflare will change your nameservers to something link alexia.cloudflare.com

Cloudflare nameserver change will only work if you change your default nameservers to point to cloudflare, some hosting companies have partnership agreements with cloudflare which makes it possible to use the cloudflare services without changing your nameserver.